# PHP - I want to try to merge a multidimensional array to only one value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge

I would like to group the following array:

```
$original = array(
'fruits' => 
    array(
        0 => '<span>banana</span>',
        1 => '<span>apple</span>',
    ), 
'others fruits' => 
    array(
        0 => '<span>pineapple</span>',
        1 => '<span>lemon</span>',
        3 => '<span>watermelon</span>'
    ), 
'more fruits' => 
    array(
        0 => '<span>strawberry</span>'
    ) );
```

Must return the original array into a single line and get this result:

```
$new = array(
'fruits' => '<span>banana</span><span>apple</span>',
'others fruits' => '<span>pineapple</span><span>lemon</span><span>watermelon</span>',
'more fruits' => '<span>strawberry</span>');
```

Answer (score 3):

Map the array elements to `implode`:

```
$result = array_map('implode', $original);
```

Comment: Thanks, AbraCadaver! Your answer was what I needed!